# Raspberry PI 2 B, creating SD card for Archlinux, fails to start

Tags: raspberry-pi2, archlinux-arm

I creating SD card by this guide: [Archlinux Raspberry-pi-2 installation](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2).
Previously everything working fine. 2016-01-11 I Archlinux OS with command "pacman -Syu". And it started to fail. And throw errors.

I think that it is becouse of SD card model and it corrupdet (see note "1").

1. So I tried to reinstall Archlinux and preapere again clean SD card.

Downloaded latest Archlinux and installed be using [same guide](http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/broadcom/raspberry-pi-2).
But it on launch still throws same error.

2. Then I tried to install Archlinux to another newly bought SD card. But same error :(.

2.1 I tried to install Raspbian to same card, and it worked perfectly.

It looks to me for now that the latest Archlinux version is faulty. What is your suggestions, how to fix this, or something now about latest Archlinux release and if it is faulty, maybe know when next version (fixed) will be release?

**See attached images with errors.**
[image]
[image]
**Note:**

1. My SD card slot (the locking mechanism) in PI is broken so I have some tape to handle it in place.
2. I am using memory **Transcend** micro SDHC 32GB w/adapt/class10 ts32gusdu1 [SD card](http://www.transcend-info.com/Products/CatList.asp?LangNo=0&ModNo=320).

Comment: This question belongs to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, next time will know that :).

Answer (score 0):

**I tried different 8 GB card and it worked.** So this is latest Archlinux version problem with that Transcend micro SDHC 32GB SD card drivers (becouse I tried two new same vendor cards and Archlinux was failing to boot). Previously (installed , updated one month before) the OS worked fine with that card.